# Spacemacs error when loading `.spacemacs` which uses package `flycheck`

Tags: spacemacs, debugging, use-package

I added the following at the end of my `~/.spacemacs` file:

```
(use-package flycheck
  :defer t
  :init (global-flycheck-mode))
```

When I do this, I get `Spacemacs encountered an error while loading your '/home/brandon/.spacemacs' file`.

How can I debug this error?

Also, is there a way to get more descriptive errors?

**Answer** to error sub-question in comments: use `emacs --debug-init`.

**Update**

The output I get when using `--debug-init` is:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function use-package)
  (use-package flycheck :defer t :init (global-flycheck-mode))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-76993> nil "/home/brandon/.spacemacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 18437
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/brandon/.spacemacs" "/home/brandon/.spacemacs" nil nil)
  load("/home/brandon/.spacemacs")
  (condition-case err (load dotspacemacs) ((debug error) (message "Error loading .spacemacs: %S" err) nil))
  (if (condition-case err (load dotspacemacs) ((debug error) (message "Error loading .spacemacs: %S" err) nil)) nil (dotspacemacs/safe-load))
  (if (file-exists-p dotspacemacs) (if (condition-case err (load dotspacemacs) ((debug error) (message "Error loading .spacemacs: %S" err) nil)) nil (dotspacemacs/safe-load)))
  (let ((dotspacemacs (dotspacemacs/location))) (if (file-exists-p dotspacemacs) (if (condition-case err (load dotspacemacs) ((debug error) (message "Error loading .spacemacs: %S" err) nil)) nil (dotspacemacs/safe-load))))
  dotspacemacs/load-file()
  spacemacs/init()
  (if (not (version<= spacemacs-emacs-min-version emacs-version)) (error (concat "Your version of Emacs (%s) is too old. " "Spacemacs requires Emacs version %s or above.") emacs-version spacemacs-emacs-min-version) (load-file (concat (file-name-directory load-file-name) "core/core-load-paths.el")) (require 'core-spacemacs) (spacemacs/init) (configuration-layer/sync) (spacemacs-buffer/display-startup-note) (spacemacs/setup-startup-hook) (require 'server) (if (server-running-p) nil (server-start)))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/brandon/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1264
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/brandon/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/brandon/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/brandon/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x25d5e9>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

**Tentative Solution**

After looking around a bit more, I realized my config was in the wrong part of the `~/.spacemacs` file. This is probably not the best place for it, but I ended up adding the following in my `(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()` ... `)`.

```
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init (global-flycheck-mode))
```

Also, I now note that flycheck complains that the line with `(use-package flycheck` has a `reference to free variable`flycheck' (emacs-lisp)` ... hmm. But, a step in the right direciton.

Comment: Try the debugging suggestions here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/wiki/Debugging#enable-debug-at-initialization  In particular, try starting spacemacs from the command line with the `--debug-init` option to get a backtrace.

Comment: Thanks for the wiki link, things are working now, though still not sure I've gotten the best approach. Seems like I should try to understand layers more (as well as emacs lisp).

Comment: In `use-package` the `:init` keyword is for code to be executed **before** the package is loaded. We can assume `global-flycheck-mode` is defined in the package, if it is being found, it is probably for some other reason. So, you should probably move that to `:config` and remove `:defer` if I understand what you want correctly. But your error message complains about `use-package` being undefined. Have you loaded `use-package` itself in your init file?